# gitlab-ci.yml - override a specific job and script execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that says:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-proj/my-gitlab-ci'
    ref: master
    file: '/pipeline/gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Because of some "Inconvenience" I would like to override some specific stage that is defined on the above mentioned `gitlab-ci.yml` file injected on my top level `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. The `plan` stage I am interested in has the following thing:

```
plan-dummy:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -lock=false -var-file=vars/vars.tfvars
```

What I want to do is override the above on the main `.gitlab-ci.yml` file such that only the script is executed as an override:

```
plan-dummy:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform refresh   # This is the line I want to add as an additional step before next 
    - terraform plan -lock=false -var-file=vars/dev.tfvars
```

How do I achieve that without fiddling with the injected file? Yes, I know that alternative is to do dirty copy-paste from child file, but I don't want to do that.

Regards,

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can do the `terraform refresh` in a `before_script` part which will be executed before you `script`:

```
plan-dummy:
  extends: plan-dummy
  before_script:
    - terraform refresh
```

Comment: Not working:
`Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:`
`plan-dummy: circular dependency detected in extends`

Comment: You don't need to specify `extends:`, simply reuse the same job name and add the configuration you need.

Answer (score 25):

simply reuse the same job name and add the configuration you need:

```
plan-dummy:
  before_script:
    - terraform refresh
```

Comment: if the original "plan-dummy" job has a"before_script" already, will listing a new command "override" it and erase the original command list?